# rename columns from list after splitting long dataframe to wide

Tags: r

Hello.

 I am trying to pull a vector of prices into a wide data frame which is inner joined by a specific column.

 Here, I used BatchGetSymbols which gives the prices in a long data frame, cleaned it, then I tried to split it by ticker name.

 This gave me a list. I then tried to join all the data frames in that list by their date.

```
tickers.tech = c("AAPL", "GPRO", "HEAR", "IRBT", "LPL", "SONO", "VUZI")

ohlc = BatchGetSymbols(tickers.tech,first.date="2018-01-01")[[2]]
test = ohlc %>% select(ticker, ref.date, ret.adjusted.prices) %>% na.omit()
x = split(test,test$ticker)

t1 = plyr::join_all(x,by="ref.date")
```

However, this left me with:

[image]

I am now trying to rename those corresponding "ret.adjusted.prices" columns with their respective ticker. ie. aapl.ret, gpro.ret, etc.

 I am pretty certain the solution to my problem comes before this point, hoping for some help. Looking for a robust solution, since I am going to be doing this with other sectors with different lengths. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the expected result is reshaped from long to wide format where the rows are identified by `ref.date` while the columns give the return value for each ticker.

This is my suggestion using my favourite toolset:

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
ohlc <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers.tech, first.date = "2018-01-01")[[2]]
ohlc %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  dcast(ref.date ~ paste0(ticker, ".ret"), value.var = "ret.adjusted.prices")
```

> ```
>        ref.date      AAPL.ret      GPRO.ret     HEAR.ret     IRBT.ret       LPL.ret     SONO.ret     VUZI.ret
>   1: 2018-01-03 -0.0001740738  0.0067204301 -0.029213483  0.036704158  0.0262225372           NA  0.000000000
>   2: 2018-01-04  0.0046451241  0.0106809079  0.030092593 -0.025529901 -0.0131215470           NA  0.023809524
>   3: 2018-01-05  0.0113852273 -0.0066050198  0.022471910  0.013346540 -0.0027991603           NA  0.186046512
>   4: 2018-01-08 -0.0037143326 -0.1276595745  0.006593407 -0.002682939  0.0007017544           NA  0.124183007
>   5: 2018-01-09 -0.0001144906 -0.0594512195 -0.028384279 -0.007459049 -0.0098176718           NA  0.017441860
>  ---                                                                                                         
> 869: 2021-06-16  0.0039339325 -0.0154471545  0.004160943  0.007272696 -0.0178217822  0.002030133  0.016235780
> 870: 2021-06-17  0.0126008381 -0.0206440958 -0.005524889 -0.016193915  0.0463709677 -0.027785790 -0.037869822
> 871: 2021-06-18 -0.0100917070 -0.0379426644 -0.083611056 -0.003984032  0.0163776493 -0.016076243 -0.031365314
> 872: 2021-06-21  0.0141039085  0.0131463628  0.006971779 -0.015473695  0.0265402844  0.036308655  0.023492127
> 873: 2021-06-22  0.0126983595 -0.0008650519 -0.050571943 -0.014220058 -0.0073868883  0.000000000  0.001240571
> ```